# Annotation.tailrec is throwing compilation error in scala

Tags: scala

I am writing merge sort program in scala 2.11.8 version.

Below is my program -

```
 object ListMergeSort {

      def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
        val list:List[Int]= List(1,5,7,2,9,3,8,6,4)
        println(list)

        println(sort(list))
      }


      def sort(l:List[Int]):List[Int]= {
        l match{
          case Nil => l
          case h::Nil => l
          case _ =>
            val (l1,l2) = l splitAt(l.length/2)
            listMergeSort(sort(l1),sort(l2))
        }
      }

      //@annotation.tailrec
      def listMergeSort(l1:List[Int],l2:List[Int]):List[Int]={
        (l1,l2) match{
          case (Nil,l2) => l2
          case (l1,Nil) => l1
          case (h1::t1, h2::t2) => if (h1<h2) h1::listMergeSort(t1,l2) else h2::listMergeSort(l1,t2)
        }
      }
    }
```

The above program works fine technically correct and the output gives me the sorted list.

I want to annotate the listMergeSort function as tail recursive but the compiler is giving error "recursive call not in tail position".

[image]

```
    import scala.util.Random        
    object test {

      def msort[T <% Ordered[T]](xs: List[T]): List[T] = {

        @annotation.tailrec
        def merge(res: List[T], xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = (xs, ys) match {
          case (_, Nil) => res.reverse ::: xs
          case (Nil, _) => res.reverse ::: ys
          case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
            if (x < y) merge(x :: res, xs1, ys)
            else merge(y :: res, xs, ys1)
        }

        val n = xs.length / 2
        if (n == 0) xs
        else {
          val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n
          merge(Nil, msort(ys), msort(zs))
        }
      }

      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val list = Seq.fill(10)(Random.nextInt(500)).toList
        println(list)
        println(msort(list))
      }
    }
```

The above program also has similar merge function but the @annotation.tailrec is not throwing any error.

can anyone help what could be the root cause of the error in my program?

Comment: yeah because one is tail recursive and the other is not.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is telling you everything there is to tell.

This line..

```
if (h1<h2) h1::listMergeSort(t1,l2) else h2::listMergeSort(l1,t2)
```

...is not tail recursive because **after** `listMergeSort()` returns there is more work to do, i.e. pre-pend the `h1` or `h2` element.

This line, on the other hand, **is** is tail recursive...

```
if (x < y) merge(x :: res, xs1, ys) else merge(y :: res, xs, ys1)
```

...because after `merge` returns there is nothing more to do, simply return whatever `merge()` returns.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to see if you write it using normal method call notation instead of infix operator notation: `if (h1<h2) listMergeSort(t1,l2).::(h1) else listMergeSort(l1,t2).::(h2)`. Here it is obvious that we call the `::` method *after* the recursive call.